# Handle multer.single('file') error when upload multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I followed the [Multer code](https://github.com/expressjs/multer):

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {

})
```

One single file should be uploaded. But if one tries to upload multiple files, how to catch the error `MulterError: Unexpected field`?

I have tried below to no success:

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    try {

    } catch (error) {
    // Why cannot catch any error?
    }
})
```

Comment: Post your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when `upload.single` executes `next()` then only it comes here,

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    try {

    } catch (error) {
        // It catches only errors from above `try block`
    }
});
```

If `upload.single` faces any error it does not call `next()` instead it gets passed to next listner. To catch any error of `upload.single` you must add this after above `app.post(/profile)`.

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    var error = err.message;
    res.status(500);
    res.send({ "error": error });
});
```